# Error with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I am trying out a simple module with requirejs.
/js/app.js

```
define(function (require, exports) {           
  var calculator = require('/js/calculator');                                     
  var result = calulator.add(1, 2);

  console.log(result);                                                               
});
```

/js/caluator.js

```
define(function (require, exports) {           
  exports = {
    add: function (one, two) {
      return one+two;
    }
  };
});
```

when I am running the app, I am get the error `Error: Script error for: calculator`

code source `https://github.com/souparno/modular-js`

Comment: Please post the error you're getting.

Comment: @benjarwar, I am put in the error msg

Comment: in caculcator.js try returning the object `return exports = {...}`

then try `calulator.add(1, 2)` - can you elaborate on the exports module? you should just be able to return an object at the bottom of your calculator script and call add on it (without use of exports). without better error reporting, its possible the require config for calculator is misconfigured via rjs

Comment: i havent used any require.config for this project.is that a problem?
I am trying to use the default funttion syntax for amd => function (require, exports, module)

Comment: i've never done it without a config, apologies. by using a require config you can define calculator.js as its own module, requiring it as you are the others. `define(['calculator'], function (calculator) { etc`

Comment: @lfender6445, can you check the code at https://github.com/souparno/modular-js

Comment: looks good  to me - you ran bower install, right? appears to be working. the return statement was probably what was needed. good job! i've updated my answer.

Comment: @lfender6445, yes, I installed it with bower. I guess the return was all that was missing. :)

Comment: great - would you mind marking my answer as correct then? this will help other users who run into the same issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

/js/app.js

```
define(function (require) {           
  var calculator = require('calculator');                                     
  var result = calulator.add(1, 2);

  console.log(result);                                                               
});
```

/js/calculator.js

```
define(function (require) {           
  return {
    add: function (one, two) {
      return one+two;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a return statement to make sure your functions are defined at the bottom of your module and properly exposed:

```
define(function (require, exports) {

 var calculator = {
     add: function (one, two) {
      return one+two;
     }
   };


  return calculator;
});
```